# Visual basic function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, ssis

We are working on a SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2016 upgrade. We are in the process of upgrading the SSIS packages. Within the packages we have a script component that saves the count in a variabl": RecordsinSource

In the visual basic 2008 version we use this piece of code to cast the count to a NVARCHAR value.

```
Dim MyRecordsInSource As String

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    MyRecordsInSource = Row.CASTCOUNT1ASNVARCHAR28
    End Sub

Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
    MyBase.PostExecute()
    Me.Variables.varRecordsInSource = MyRecordsInSource
    End Sub
```

But after we execute the package in the 2015 version the code gets transormed to the following and gives an conversion error. Notice the CASTCOUNT1ASNVARCHAR28 has ben changed by visual studio or vb to ToString

```
Dim MyRecordsInSource As String

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    MyRecordsInSource = Row.ToString()
    End Sub

Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
    MyBase.PostExecute()
    Me.Variables.varRecordsInSource = MyRecordsInSource
    End Sub
```

Does anyone recognize this issue or is there a way to Cast the variable without using the ToString function

I get the following error at my logging. When I replace the toString with the old code CASTCOUNT1ASNVARCHAR28 all boxes check green. With Tostring() I get a failure at the Execute SQL Task :

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "insert into etl.process_stagingin_log (BatchNr 
, ..." failed with the following error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SC_64e4ca4597264faf93443f856b4b31a2.Input0Buffer' to data type int.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

The SC_64e4ca4597264faf93443f856b4b31a2 is the name of the vb script. And the inpt0Buffer is the part where the conversion funcion is

Comment: You don't cast numbers to nvarchar. You generate strings from them. That's what `ToString()` does. What conversion error are you talking about anyway? What's the *actual* error message? You don't need *code* to do that in SSIS by the way - never did. Add a `Derived Column` transformation and write the appropriate VBScript expression. Unfortunately, VBScript has *very* poor formatting support. You'll have to use the [casting operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression) that only allow you to specify lengths and *sometimes* locales

Comment: BTW there's no `CASTCOUNT1ASNVARCHAR28` method. The script transformation generates many classes. It looks like someone modified the generated Row class and added a `CASTCOUNT1ASNVARCHAR28` method. From the name it sounds like like someone wanted to convert the `(DT_WSTR,28)Count1` expression to code? Most likely the conversion code found the unknown method and replaced it with `ToString()`. This will return the custom type's name

Comment: Where do you get the conversion error and what does it say? `Row.ToString()` won't raise any such error. Are you trying to store a *string*  generated from a *number* into value in a *numeric* field? You may be able to fix the problem by simply removing this transformation then.

Comment: I get the following error at my logging. When I replace the toString with the old code CASTCOUNT1ASNVARCHAR28 all boxes check green. With Tostring() I get a failure at the Execute SQL Task :

Comment: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "insert into etl.process_stagingin_log (BatchNr 
, ..." failed with the following error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

Comment: Read the error. It says that you tried to insert a *string* into a numeric field. Which is what the original code says it does - you still haven't posted the contents of the `CASTCOUNT1ASNVARCHAR28` function.  *Don't* convert the count to a string, ie remove this transformation completely and use the count field in the Execute SQL Task directly as a paremeter.

Comment: As for replacing *your method* with `ToString()`, yes, of course it would fail. `ToString()` means make a string out of this object, in this case, the entire row. You want to call your own method, add your own method. Although I suspect you don't need any method, just all this code and use your COUNT1 field as is in the Execute SQL Task.

Comment: What does the Execute SQL task look like and why does it need the count as a string parameter? If it the query was `insert into etl.process_stagingin_log (BatchNr ,...) VALUES (?,?,?)` and the parameters had the *correct* types there would be no conversion and thus no error